# Left aligned divs with equal horizontal margins

Tags: html, css

I have a number of inline-block elements I wish to house inside a container div. As the container div is resized the number of in-line block elements appearing across/up/down change. I wish to keep these divs left-aligned such that they appear like:

```
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXX
```

and **not** like:

```
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
  XXX
```

But need to maintain equal margins left and right. So the left and right most divs are equidistant from the edges of the container at all times:

```
|<-XXXXXXX->|
|<-XXXXXXX->|
|<-XXX      |
```

How can I do this in pure CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/e818rfum/

Comment: I seem to recall this issue coming up many times before and, I don't remember ever seeing a CSS solution...yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Center Cards within Div While Maintaining a Left-Align](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858567/how-to-center-cards-within-div-while-maintaining-a-left-align)

Comment: @Paulie_D flexbox? but with limited browser support.

Comment: I remember solving a similar problem using jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: @MarcAudet I don't recall a flexbox solution...I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of blocks defined that are allowed per line? Or rather has the inner container (`.left`) a maximum width? Just asking because I fail to see the condition when those equal margins are to be applied.

Comment: @maryisdead Hadn't defined any but I suppose I could. You can assume there's an upper limit if you need to for a solution.

Comment: I feel like wrapping your left aligned divs with a wrapper div that has a `width: 80%` and a `margin: 0 auto;` would come close to your little text demo above.  Have you tried something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/e818rfum/4/

Comment: @robabby Would look closer but only because the absolute difference in margins has been reduced but the problem remains.

Comment: Ah, I guess I don't fully understand the problem then.  Good luck!

Comment: Do you need the width of the divs to be constant during window resizing or could it be dynamic, e.g. 20% instead of 100px?

Comment: They should be absolutely sized. The idea is to show more divs/row if the user's window is larger, not just increase their size.

Comment: Okay so what you want is a variable margin in between the fix divs so they nicely use all the available space until there is enough to add an additional div per row? I guess there is only flexbox or JS for this. I'll setup a fiddle to answer this later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to go for a CSS only solution, I'd suggest you to use a centered container for the individual items + media queries to to adjust the width of this container during resizing.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ddd;
}

@media (min-width: 110px) { .container { width: 110px; } }
@media (min-width: 220px) { .container { width: 220px; } }
@media (min-width: 330px) { .container { width: 330px; } }
@media (min-width: 440px) { .container { width: 440px; } }
@media (min-width: 550px) { .container { width: 550px; } }
@media (min-width: 660px) { .container { width: 660px; } }
@media (min-width: 770px) { .container { width: 770px; } }
@media (min-width: 880px) { .container { width: 880px; } }
@media (min-width: 990px) { .container { width: 990px; } }

.item {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 5px;
}

.container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

You can also access this demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prud/n7q2qovy/).

Instead of resizing the container width, which results in varying left/right margins, you could also have percentage values for the items margin or width. Its basically a question of what you want to be your dynamic value in here:

- variable container margin (see demo)
- variable item margins
- variable item widths

Its all possible via CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want. Downside here is obviously the reliance on pixel values. Also switched from `display: inline` to `float: left` for the sake of not having to troll myself with gaps and line-height.

```css
.block{
    float:left;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.container{
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding:5px;
}
.left{
    text-align:left;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 220px; /* Max. four items per row, margins included */
    overflow: hidden; /* Cheap-skate clearfix */
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/aw3k43x3/))

Comment: Perfect for exactly 4 across but still not responsive. Container may assume a maximum width but has to work for any dimensions up to the specified maximum.

Comment: Hm. What exactly do you mean by responsive? Is `.block` a defined pixel value as given in your example? Do you want `max-width` to be a percentage? Guess, I haven't fully grasped what you're trying to achieve then. Can you specify a use-case that isn't covered by my answer?

Comment: Shrinks your window so only 3 red boxes can fit across. You'll notice a large gap on the right but the left hand side remains perfectly snug with .left's border. .block's are defined as pixel values but .container (and .left) must be able to maintain the layout while being resized.

Answer (score 0):

After giving up on the CSS I've thrown together this really ugly piece of jQuery to do what I want. Posting it here if only to clarify the desired behavior.

```
function doLayout(){
        var canFitAcross = Math.floor($(".container").innerWidth()/$(".block").outerWidth(true));
        var reals = $(".container .block:not(.fake)").length;
        var fakes = $(".container .fake").length;
        if((reals+fakes)%canFitAcross!=0){
            $(".fake").remove();
            var neededFakes = canFitAcross-(reals%canFitAcross);
            if(neededFakes!=canFitAcross){
                for(var i=0;i<neededFakes;i++){
                    $(".container").append("<div class='block fake'></div>");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Here I've done away with .left entirely. In its place "fake" (visibility:hidden, opacity:0.5 for demonstration purposes) .block elements are used to get the desired left-alignment.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/mgx37q5m/

Still hoping for some kind of CSS solution...